# Can IE execute two JavaScript functions concurrently

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, dom-events, watin

We are using WatiN from C# to interact with a browser (currently only IE).

Some of WatiN's methods are a simple wrapper that sends an `onchanged()` and `onclick()` to certain web elements.

WatiN also provides a fire-and-forget version for this, which basically provides a non blocking version.

My question is, does the browser also two JS functions to execute at the same time?

For example, assume the following code:

```
// Uses FireEventAsync("onchanged")
SelectList.SelectNoWait()

SelectList.FireEventAsync("onclick")
```

Can both JS functions onclick and onchanged execute at once?

I believe we are experiencing a similar issue, where an `onchanged()` function is still executing while we fire another event, I was wondering if that is technically possible.

Comment: It would depend on the browser I suspect.

Comment: Javascript exectuing is event-driven, so when you are firing `onclick` and `onchange` browser just adds handlers to the execution queue. Than, they are executed sequentially.

So, if your question is "is it possible to fire to events simultaneously" - the answer is definitely yes. But, I think the order in which they are got executed are not guaranteed.

Comment: Updated my question with the browser type (IE).

Comment: @J0HN is there any link/documentation regarding the execution model, to read up on how this actually gets done?

Comment: @J0HN has it basically right.  The only thing I'd like to clarify is that the function execution in the browser is not *actually* simultaneous, so there is no risk of a race condition if the functions are not atomic.  If you fire an event while another function is executing, it should simply be queued up for handling when the current function is done.

Comment: @lysergic-acid searched the net for an hour yesterday but haven't find any documentation. But it must exist somewhere, I saw it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no. JavaScript execution is single-threaded.

However, with asynchronous operations (ajax, timers, workers, etc.), parts of a function can be setup to be executed later when the thread is free.

A contrived example would be:

```
function foo() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('three');
    }, 10);

    console.log('one');
}

function bar() {
    console.log('two');
}

foo();
bar();
```

Though `foo` and `bar` are called synchronously and the logs are written in order of `three, one, two`, they will be executed in order of `one, two, three` as the timer will delay the log of '`three'` for later.

And, even if your handlers don't use anything asynchronous, `SelectNoWait` and `FireEventAsync` likely do.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the implementation of FireEventAsync. This means there CAN be a potential race condition going on which causes weird behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

No, as long as you don't specifically use [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/Using_DOM_workers), you can't have multiple executions at the same time. Only one user thread can be active in a browser context.

Usually you execute only small functions wich are called on events, most long tasks being  related to resources and asynchronous.

When you think "event based" and (most importantly) don't try to make synchronous calls from what is naturally asynchronous (I think about AJAX), you have no problems.

Comment: That's a shame, as what we're experiencing seems "race condition" like and pretty random. I have thought my theory could explain it.